# Fact table design - One-to-many

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

I come from a relational SQL Server database background, and am trying to make the transition to a multi-dimensional model in Analysis Services.

I'm struggling with how to approach the following problem, which would be incredibly simple in the relational world.

I have 3 tables - Incident, IncidentOffender, and IncidentLoss. There may be none, one, or many IncidentOffenders and IncidentLosses to an Incident:

[image]

How can I design my data warehouse such that I will be able to ask the cube, for example, "how much time did we spend dealing with incidents on which a bald offender stole baked beans?", as well as "what was the value of those beans?"?

Apologies if this sounds simple, but I've scoured the web and devoured various books, but still I cannot find a real-life example of anything like this, which seems like an everyday situation to me.

Comment: Looks fine to me, but I suppose I would model IncidentLoss as the fact table and Incident and IncidentOffender as dimensions.

Comment: Thanks - would FactIncidentLoss then contain an IncidentLossID, IncidentID, and IncidentOffenderID? It's the last of those that's causing a problem - because there may be more than one IncidentOffender to an Incident.

Comment: With that requirement, I'd go with a mapping m:n table and test carefully for performance issues.

Comment: Thanks - is that what you'd class as a 'bridge table'?

Comment: I think this is exactly a bridge table after Kimball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, all three tables need to be loaded into SSAS as both dimensions and measure groups. Then the Incident Offender and Incident Loss dimensions can be many-to-many dimensions for the Incident measure group. It will look like the following in the Dimension Usage tab.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this - it's actually the solution I've settled on with the first cube I built, but I never felt entirely comfortable with it. Would 'best practice' here be to build 2 cubes (or more if necessary), each with a single fact table at the finest possible granularity?

Comment: No. A single fact table per cube is definitely not a best practice. There is a lot of power in analyzing measures from different fact tables in the same report. That's a bit off topic since in your case the other two fact tables are just bridge tables for the many-to-many dimensions.

Comment: No problem @GregGalloway. I'm still mulling things over but will definitely mark this as the accepted answer once I'm happy.

Comment: One more question - I was taught that it's best to aim for a star schema, but these bridge tables appear to break that pattern and result in a snowflake. Is that true? Is it worth worrying about?

Comment: @Nugsson a snowflake would be when the fact table foreign keys to the customer dimension which foreign keys to the geography dimension. That's not the scenario here. I view this as a valid model since each incident has multiple loss categories and multiple offenders. Other than separating the model into explicit fact and dimension tables in SQL I wouldn't change anything.